# Scape span, within DIV using Python

Tags: python, scrape

Trying to gather a list, using Python, of the Amazon Prime available movies from website:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557596014&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_nr_p_72_4

I have tried to locate the title of the movie but returning 0. This must be from the page loading JavaScript first, I've looked in NETWORK but can't work out what I'm looking for.

I've attempted the following code:

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557596014&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_nr_p_72_4'
response = get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
type(html_soup)
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'a-size-medium     a-color-base a-text-normal')
print(type(movie_containers))
print(len(movie_containers))
```

I've then tried to loop around:

```
for n in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'a-size-medium     a-color-base a-text-normal'}):
    title.append (n.text)
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Results should extract title and link for each movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include a header of the get request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"}
a = requests.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557596014&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_nr_p_72_4", headers=header)
b = BeautifulSoup(a.text, "html.parser")
for c in b.find_all("span", class_="a-size-medium"):
    print(c.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Still can't extract the titles using code above?

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to go to page 2, page 3 etc?

Comment: I suggest analyzing what difference each URL has; page 2 or 3.

Comment: When I change the page reference, the output is the same. It's very strange.

Comment: you can find difference of each url's parameters!

Comment: page 1 `https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&page=1&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557672988&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_pg_1`

Comment: page 2 `https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&page=2&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557672988&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_pg_2`

Comment: page 3 `https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=instant-video&bbn=3010085031&rh=n%3A3010085031%2Cp_85%3A3282143031%2Cp_72%3A3289786031&dc&page=3&adult-product=0&field-genre=-family&field-review_count=3-&field-ways_to_watch=7448662031&p_n_entity_type=9739952031&qid=1557673010&qs-av_request_type=4&qs-is-prime-customer=0&rnid=3289782031&ref=sr_pg_3`

Comment: Hi, I've tried doing that - changing the URL to search from sr_pg_2 to sr_pg_3 but comes out the same result?

Comment: page=1, page=2 and page=3

Comment: Does this then become ... 3289782031&ref=sr_pg_3&page=1 ?